# Download selective files from S3 using S3 Golang SDK

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I am using Golang SDK to communicate with AWS S3. I want to download only those files from a folder, that ends with .txt or .lib.

Comment: have you tried listing objects and then downloading them?

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that. I was wondering if there is a direct way.

Comment: aws doesn't have an api to download an entire folder or process items in that folder. Any direct method you may find, would only be an abstraction of listing items and then using regex to find items belonging to a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS SDK does not have this possibility. 
You can list objects in a bucket, filter the output based on your needs and get a single object using getObject.
see here [GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.GetObject) and here [ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjects)

Another option can be to mount AWS S3 bucket on your machine/server using e.g. [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) and filter the files you need in order to get the list to download.